# .Net Documentation of Interface Overloads not displayed in Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, .net-standard

I am having a difficult time with documenting my class library correctly. I have an Interface with overloads for almost all methods like this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get JSON result deserialized to custom type. Accepts advanced options.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Deserialized response of T</returns>
Task<CustomHttpResponse<T>> GetJSON<T>(RextOptions options); //shows up on intellisense
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// Get JSON result deserialized to custom type
/// </summary>
Task<CustomHttpResponse<T>> GetJSON<T>(string url, object payload = null, object header = null); //does not show
```

So I reordered the methods, tried several tweaks i found online but still doesn't work as seen below.

Method 1 works

[image: Method 1 showing the documentation info by referenced class]

Method 2 (overload) doesn't

[image: Method 2 (overload) documentation is blank]

I also examined many Interfaces from Microsoft and documentations in methods with overloads in Interfaces work just fine. Please i need help with this. Thank you.

Comment: You show us code of `GetJSON` methods, yet images of `GetString` methods.

Comment: So the one that shows has a `<returns>` and the one that does not does not. something to try fixing?

Comment: did you try to clean then build your solution ?

Comment: @sayahimad i did that multiple times

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes sorry for that, but both GetString and GetJSON have same signatures and same problem

Comment: Note that documentation in interfaces is not automatically displayed for their implementations.

Comment: Please is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: See: [<inheritdoc> (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc). Note: `<inheritdoc>` is quite a new possibility added to doc comments.

Comment: I finally fixed it.. See my answer., thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue

The XML body for the doc on those methods were wrongly formed. I added < > to the content so it was skipped.

I just had to pay attention to the comment and fix it, then it worked.
[image]

I also found this on the Doc.xml fil
[image]

Thanks for the concern.

Comment: We could have found it, if you had shown us the real Xml-comment instead of a dummy or a different one.

Comment: ... and please, as text, not as image, so we can copy paste it into VS to make tests.